# Should the Table of Contents be title case?

Tags: titles, capitalization, table-of-contents

I did read [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)

Now I'm asking myself when creating the "Table of Contents" for a book should I apply there the same rules for capitalization in the content list as for the title on the page. Or should I go with a lower case version like it is a normal sentence there.

Comment: If the contents are chapters with individual titles, of course you follow the same guidelines as for the book title.

Comment: Basically, yes. The main words and first word are capitalized, and connection words are not: The Beginning of Time Also, I suggest you google some papers and look at them.

Comment: Follow your style guide here.   I would say: If you use a certain capitalization in the title of a chapter, then use the same capitalization whenever you mention that title elsewhere, including within the Table of Contents.

Comment: I would recommend one of @GEdgar or Lambie or Kate-Bunting turn their comment into the answer it is. GEdgar's comment seems the most complete but otherwise any of those seem to be viable answers to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow your style guide here. I would say: If you use a certain capitalization in the title of a chapter, then use the same capitalization whenever you mention that title elsewhere, including within the Table of Contents.